# Why is my function not returning?

Tags: c

I have a function called gets_timeout which functions similar to the normal gets function. However, it has a timeout function, where it will simply return after a certain length of time. Before I add the "timeout" part to my code, I have made the rest of the function which should read a specified number of characters before returning.

```
void gets_timeout(uint8_t *dest, int dest_size)
{
    int i;

    memset(dest, '.', dest_size);


    for(i = 0; dest_size; i++)
    {
        dest[i] = getch();

    }
}
```

And then I'm calling it with:

```
uint8_t buffer[15];
gets_timeout(buffer, 15);

for(m = 0; m < 15; m++)
{
    printf("%c", buffer[m]);
}
```

However my function never returns and I am unable to figure out why.

Comment: Did you think of using the `return` statement?

Comment: for(i = 0; dest_size; i++)   ????

Answer (score 3):

In

```
for(i = 0; dest_size; i++)
```

the condition part of the loop just checks if the value of `dest_size` exists and is a non zero value. Since you are sending a value which would keep the condition `true`, it would go into an infinite loop.
So changing it to

```
for(i = 0; i < dest_size; i++)
```

would end the loop at some time when `i < dest_size` fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; dest_size; i++)
```

The condition `dest_size` will always evaluate to `true` (when `dest_size != 0`). Thus the function will loop infinitely.

It should probably be `i < dest_size`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
for(i = 0; dest_size; i++)
```

with

```
for(i = 0; i < dest_size; i++)
```